# Find assembly's public key via code

Tags: .net, public-key

How can I find a .NET assembly's public key via code?

From the command line, I can use sn -Tp *assemblyName* to find the public key.

What's the equivalent (c# or VB) in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [`AssemblyName.GetPublicKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getpublickey.aspx) method.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Byte[] key = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKey();

        foreach (Byte b in key)
            Console.Write("{0:x}", b);
    }
}
```